Allow localhost insecure certificate for https
I have a local angular project that needs an HTTPS endpoint.
My project is started  with
ng serve --ssl --configuration development.
Even when I turn of the https warning my page is not loaded and the requests show as failed in network tab.
I wasn't able to find any switch in the settings to allow loading content from localhost with a self-signed certificate.
Adding the certificate is not really an option as it will change frequently.

I found a flag in the about://flags page.
To directly change the setting go to about://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost and switch to enabled.

Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.
Allows requests to localhost over HTTPS even when an invalid certificate is presented. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Android, Lacros

